# Reorder array of objects in specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays one is `contentOrder` that basically is and array of ids and the other one is `blocksContent` that is and array of objects, i want order the second array using the order of the ids from the first array how can id do this.

**contentOrder**

```
contentOrder = [
    "de19b7c5-ff69-4fce-a38d-c6f0ee0d1eb5",
    "58f0dcfe-55d8-447d-87cc-fc00ec068407",
    "58f0dcfe-55d8-447d-87cc-fc00ec085407"
    ]
```

**blocksContent**

```
blocksContent= [
  {blockId: "58f0dcfe-55d8-447d-87cc-fc00ec068407", documentId: 298, chapterId: "4c26640a-bcda-4788-aee3-5c1508f70a67"},
  {blockId: "58f0dcfe-55d8-447d-87cc-fc00ec085407", documentId: 298, chapterId: "4c26640a-bcda-4788-aee3-5c1508f70a67"}
  {blockId: "de19b7c5-ff69-4fce-a38d-c6f0ee0d1eb5", documentId: 298, chapterId: "4c26640a-bcda-4788"}
]
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Any attempt to show?

Comment: I can't believe that StackOverflow recommends to "Downvote and move on" instead of asking OP what they've tried O_o Seriously??

Comment: @JeremyThille I didn't downvote and move on, but it's expcted that users are familiar with how asking a question works. A question like this one means the user didn't bother reading the guides or didn't care enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort` and `indexOf` functions.

```js
var contentOrder = [
    "de19b7c5-ff69-4fce-a38d-c6f0ee0d1eb5",
    "58f0dcfe-55d8-447d-87cc-fc00ec068407",
    "58f0dcfe-55d8-447d-87cc-fc00ec085407"
    ]


var blocksContent= [
  {blockId: "58f0dcfe-55d8-447d-87cc-fc00ec068407", documentId: 298, chapterId: "4c26640a-bcda-4788-aee3-5c1508f70a67"},
  {blockId: "58f0dcfe-55d8-447d-87cc-fc00ec085407", documentId: 298, chapterId: "4c26640a-bcda-4788-aee3-5c1508f70a67"},
  {blockId: "de19b7c5-ff69-4fce-a38d-c6f0ee0d1eb5", documentId: 298, chapterId: "4c26640a-bcda-4788"}
]

blocksContent.sort((a, b) => contentOrder.indexOf(a.blockId) - contentOrder.indexOf(b.blockId));

console.log(blocksContent);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `indexOf` would work too, without a callback.

Comment: @NinaScholz you're totally right!

Comment: @Ele Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: @MiguelAngelFrias you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
let sortedContent = []

contentOrder.forEach((val) => {
  blocksContent.forEach((val1)=> {
    if(val == val1.blockId)
      sortedContent.push(val1)
  })
})
```